# Redirect url to new subdomain when old domain have paramater

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect when old domain have parameter. 
ex: domain.com/123456 -> sub.domain.com/123456
If old domain don't have parameter do not redirect.
ex: domain.com/about.php still not redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to the top of the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for help.
It's work all redirect, but I want to keep without parameter id ([0-9]+) do not redirect to the subdomain.